# How to order by in Django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-tables2

I have implemented django-tables2 in my project. But I am not able to order by one of the fields (which I called from outside the app(model)). When I click on the ordering button in the GUI it is not working as expected.

The following is the code:

```
validation_time = tables.Column(accessor='model.history', verbose_name="Validation Time")
```

Here is the code to call that field:

```
def render_validation_time(self, value):
    try:
        x = value.filter(field_name__iexact='status').latest('id')
        validated_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x.date_modified)).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return "--"
    else:
        return validated_time
```

Comment: Do I need to pre-process it?

Answer (score 2):

To make a column orderable in Django-tables2 you only need to add

```
orderable=True
```

to the column and when you render the table in the template that field will be orderable.

Your column should be like this:

```
validation_time = tables.Column(accessor='model.history', orderable=True, verbose_name="Validation Time")
```

If you're overwritting the rendering method I don't know if this will work as expected